# Qt: Disable QMessageLogger?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, qt5

I have a multi-threaded Windows app where I'm using just the core Qt5 parts like QString etc. and some of the XML functionality. I noticed that, out of the blue, a thread managed by Qt is using all CPU time on a single core. I'm definitely not using any of Qt's debug logging etc.

Looking at the stack trace, I can see stuff like:

KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
OutputDebugStringA+0x77
KERNELBASE!OutputDebugStringW+0xc6
Qt5Core!QMessageLogger::warning+0x15b
Qt5Core!QMessageLogger::noDebug+0x58c
Qt5Core!qt_message_output+0x1fa
Qt5Core!QCoreApplicationPrivate::qmljsDebugArgumentsString+0x8f
Qt5Core!QMessageLogger::warning+0x3b
Qt5Core!QThread::msleep+0x550

I've never seen this before. I don't use QMessageLogger, don't need it and don't want it, but I'm unsure on how to make sure this isn't created. I saw some documentation on how to disable certain levels (e.g. prevent warnings) but nothing on how to just entirely shut this off.

I'm using Visual Studio to compile. I'm not on the latest Qt5 but on 5.11.

Comment: Did you look at the message its trying to log? Perhaps your threads have some issue that causes Qt to complain to the logger. In my int main() I usually install a message handler using qInstallMessageHandler() and have an assert in debug mode after filtering some messages that I need to ignore. And yes I am using Qt5 and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. Looking at it again, it doesn't look like the thread is always active. Something must have happened that started the thread, yet there seems to be a bug that causes it use all CPU time for some reason.